# Read till end of file into array

Tags: c, arrays, file, eof, scanf

I've been trying to figure where I'm going wrong but I can't seem to point out where my error is exactly.

I'm trying to read from my text file, these integers

```
5 2 4 9 10 1 8 13 12 6 3 7 11
```

into an array A. To make sure it works, I was trying to print A but only getting large random numbers instead. Can someone help me see where i'm going wrong please?

```
int main(){

FILE* in = fopen("input.txt","r");

int A[100];

while(!feof(in)){
    fscanf(in, "%s", &A);
    printf("%d", A)
  }

 fclose(in);
 return 0;
}
```

*this is just the main parts of the code related to the question

Comment: Please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: You need to read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/3386109) about the basics of C programming.

Comment: As for your problem, you're printing the *address* of  where the first element of `A` is stored (i.e. `&A[0]`).

Comment: Maybe `int i = 0, A[100] = {0}; while (i < 100 && fscanf (in, " %d", &A[i]) == 1) {printf (" %d", A[i]; i++;}` ?

Comment: Please format your code and fix the syntax errors. Right now your code cannot be compiled.

Comment: Thank you David, that's EXACTLY what i was looking for. I couldn't remember how to format the while loop like this. It works perfect now

Answer (score 1):

For all those who actually read why using `feof` is always wrong, the solution is something similar to the following. The code will open the filename given as the first argument to the program (or read from `stdin` by default):

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXI = 100 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int i = 0, A[MAXI] = {0};   /* initialize variables */
    /* read from file specified as argument 1 (or stdin, default) */
    FILE *in = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1],"r") : stdin;

    if (!in) {  /* validate file opened for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each number from file or until array full */
    while (i < MAXI && fscanf (in, " %d", &A[i]) == 1)
        printf (" %d", A[i++]);
    putchar ('\n');

    if (in != stdin) fclose (in);

    printf ("\n '%d' numbers read from the file.\n\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your example values in the file `dat/myints.txt` results in the following:

```
$ ./bin/rdints dat/myints.txt
 5 2 4 9 10 1 8 13 12 6 3 7 11

 '13' numbers read from the file.
```